# How to split matrices by ids in the first column + creating incidence matrix for each id?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to calculate a Euclidean distance between two law firms in terms of the market shares of their branch offices (For now).

Later I will have to calculate every possible distances between two firms in 400 law firms sample.

Put simply, I have data, such as:

```
Firm  Year  Location  Market_share
1     2000     1         0.1
1     2000     2         0.2
1     2000     3         0.5
1     2000     4         0.2
1     2001     1         0.3
1     2001     2         0.0
1     2001     3         0.2 
1     2001     4         0.5
2     2000     1         0.0
2     2000     2         0.4
2     2000     3         0.2
2     2000     4         0.4
2     2001     1         0.1
2     2001     2         0.5
2     2001     3         0.3
1     2001     4         0.1
```

The above data will be "balanced" panel data for every firm, so the size of the matrix will be the same. Each firm will have about 200 branch locations and 35 years of branch history.

I want to transform this data into a Year X Location incidence matrix for every firm id with cell values representing its marketshare.

Such as:

Firm 1

```
            Location 1 Location 2 Location 3 Location 4 
 2000          0.1        0.2       0.5         0.2 
 2001          0.3        0         0.2         0.5
```

Firm 2

```
            Location 1 Location 2 Location 3 Location 4 
 2000          0         0.4        0.2        0.4
 2001          0.1       0.5        0.3        0.1
```

and so on...

What I need to do is:

1. Split the above matrix by unique firm id in the first column
2. Remove the first column that contains the id info
3. Turn the remaining matrix into Year X Location incidence matrix by using (sparse) command.
4. Carry out the euclidean distance calculation for all possible combination of firm i and firm j.

How might I approach this?

Comment: If your dataset is that small, you don't need to create sparse matrix.

Comment: Actually, the original dataset have 400 law firms and each of theem has about 200 branch locations and their history goes back to 35 years... I am so sure how to approach this.. or if this case in matlab is considered a small data set..

Comment: I see, so it depends on how frequent the firms are present on the 200 branch locations. A sparse representation only makes sense when there are a good amount of zeros. But anyway, this is not the key point here. You could use a cell array for the firmas representation, and the line as year, columns as location. If a good sould don't help you, I may do that tomorrow…

Comment: Don't forget to format your questions well x)

Answer (score 1):

If you need your data representation as you said here:

```
2000 0 0.4 0.2 0.4
2001 0.3 0 0.2 0.5
```

What you do is as follows, suppose you have a data matrix representation with the line and column representation as you showed and named as `oldRepresentation` (which means that the lines are observations, and the columns the Firm, Year Location and Market Share). You will have one new representation for each firma, where you will have one line for each unique year, in crescent order, and one column for the locations. It may, or may not, be a sparse representation, only use sparse representation if the matrix are sparse, not the case you showed here.

Here is a script to change the representation, **but please notice that the stackoverflow doesn't work this way**. You must code it yourself, and bring us your coding issues and where you are stuck with. Since you said that you are a beginner, here is an idea for you to work with and study the matlab syntax. Use it to workout the other points, as the euclidean distance you need. Remember, you should try to make your questions as much generic as possible.

```
oldRepresentation = [...
...% Firm  Year  Location  Market_share
      1     2000     1         0.1;...
      1     2000     2         0.2;...
      1     2000     3         0.5;...
      1     2000     4         0.2;...
      1     2001     1         0.3;...
      1     2001     2         0.0;...
      1     2001     3         0.2;...
      1     2001     4         0.5;...
      2     2000     1         0.0;...
      2     2000     2         0.4;...
      2     2000     3         0.2;...
      2     2000     4         0.4;...
      2     2001     1         0.1;...
      2     2001     2         0.5;...
      2     2001     3         0.3;...
      1     2001     4         0.1];

% Firm information (if you know these information a priori, you can
% set them directly):
firmsNumbers = unique(oldRepresentation(:,1))'; % Get unique firm
% numbers (suppose you have a firma that doesnt have a representation,
% in this case you will jump it.
nFirms = numel(firmsNumbers); % Total number of firms

% Year information:
years = unique(oldRepresentation(:,2))'; % Get unique years
nYears = numel(years); % Total number of years:

% Location information:
location = unique(oldRepresentation(:,3))'; % Unique locations
nLocations = max(oldRepresentation(:,3)); % Total number of locations

newRepresentation = cell(1,nFirms); % Pre allocate holder for the new
% representation, one cell for each firma, sparse representation.
nonSparse = cell(1,nFirms); % Pre allocate holder for the new
% representation, one cell for each firma, non sparse representation.

for curFirm=firmsNumbers % Loop on the firms
  firmLines=(oldRepresentation(:,1)==curFirm); % get lines which the

  % firm appears
  yearsOfOperation=oldRepresentation(firmLines,2); % get current firm
  % operation years
  % Transform the years to line indexes:
  [~,lineIdx] = ismember(yearsOfOperation,years);
  firmLocations=oldRepresentation(firmLines,3); % get current firm
  % operation locations
  newRepresentation{curFirm} = sparse(nYears,nLocations); % One line
  % for each year, one column for each location (sparse matrix
  % allocation).
  nonSparse{curFirm} = zeros(nYears,nLocations);
  marketShares=oldRepresentation(firmLines,4);
  % Now we fill this firm market share:
  for k=1:numel(yearsOfOperation)
    newRepresentation{curFirm}(lineIdx(k),firmLocations(k)) = ...
      marketShares(k);
    nonSparse{curFirm}(lineIdx(k),firmLocations(k)) = ...
      marketShares(k);
  end
end
```

Results non sparse representation:

```
>> nonSparse{1} % First firma, first line is the 2000 year, each column a location from 1 to 4.

ans =

    0.1000    0.2000    0.5000    0.2000
    0.3000         0    0.2000    0.1000

>> nonSparse{2} % Second firma

ans =

         0    0.4000    0.2000    0.4000
    0.1000    0.5000    0.3000         0
```

Sparse representation:

```
>> newRepresentation{1} % First firm

ans =

   (1,1)       0.1000
   (2,1)       0.3000
   (1,2)       0.2000
   (1,3)       0.5000
   (2,3)       0.2000
   (1,4)       0.2000
   (2,4)       0.1000

>> newRepresentation{2} % Second firm

ans =

   (2,1)       0.1000
   (1,2)       0.4000
   (2,2)       0.5000
   (1,3)       0.2000
   (2,3)       0.3000
   (1,4)       0.4000
```

Comment: @user2693233 you may update your question if you have trouble while trying to make the firms euclidian distance calculation.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR VERY THOROUGH ANSWER

Comment: THOUGH I AM TOTALLY NEW TO PROGRAMMING AND NOT FAMILIAR WITH THE LANGUAGE, I THINK THIS WILL BE THE FIRST STEPPING STONE FOR ME TO THINK ABOUT THE PROBLEM IN MATLAB LANGUAGE. Yes, I will try to interpret what you have suggested me to do above and come up with next questions with my own attempted codes.. thank you so much..

Comment: @user2693233 Great. When you have accomplished or have more question update the dialog here (either by commenting or updating your question). Don't forget to accept the answers here in stackoverflow when this subject is over.